# How do I write a loop to read text file and insert it to the database

Tags: sql-server, loops, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to load text files from a specific folder into SQL server database, I have manage to do so but only one file by one file. I want the program to do this automatically once the user inputs the path and the file extension.

For example:

Under C:\Test path, I have:

1. Test1.txt
2. Test2.txt
3. Test3.txt
4. Abcd.txt

I want to have the program to loop through the file and insert it to the database automatically. The number of files in the folder can vary from 10 files to 100s of files and the numbers of columns for each file are not fixed

What I’ve done so far:

1. Created a stored procedure in the SQL Server to create a new table based on the file name and calling it through my powershell script.
2. Wrote the powershell script that needs users to input the path, the filename, and the extension (txt,csv,etc) and once the details are captured it will create a table in the SQL server.

Right now, I’m stuck at the looping process as I can’t figure it out how to make the program read Test1.txt insert it to SQL server  then proceeds to read Test2.txt insert it to SQL server, until end of file in that particular folder.

Here's the script:

```
Function AutoImportFlatFiles
(
$location = $(read-host "Folder Location ('C:\Test\' okay)"), 
$file = $(read-host "File Name Without Extension ('Test1' okay)"),
$extension = $(read-host "File Extension ('.txt' okay)"),
$server, 
$database
)

{
$full = $location + $file + $extension
$columns = Get-Content $full | Select -First 1
$columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
$columns = $columns.Replace("|","] VARCHAR(2000), [")
$table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(2000))"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$buildTable = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$insertData = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $server + ";Database=" + $database + ";integrated security=true"
$buildTable.CommandText = $table
$buildTable.Connection = $connection
## Added to function
$x = 0
$insertData.CommandText = "EXECUTE stp_BulkInsert @1,@2"
$insertData.Parameters.Add("@1", $full)
$insertData.Parameters.Add("@2", $file)
$insertData.Connection = $connection
$connection.Open()
$buildTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
## Added to function
$x = 1
if ($x = 1)
{
    $connection.Open()
    $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
}
}
AutoImportFlatFiles -server "WIN123" -database "DB_DISCOVERY"
```

Comment: Do you want the user to enter each file name manually?

Comment: Nope, once the user keys in the path, I want the script to read all the files in that particular path automatically. The way I'm doing it now is having the user to key in one by one which what I'm trying to get rid off. Any suggestions on how to archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a simple loop, you can use your existing **AutoImportFlatFiles** function like this:

```
$Folder= $(read-host "Folder Location ('C:\Test\' okay)")
foreach ($file in (get-childitem $Folder)) {
    $location = split-path $file.FullName -Parent
    $filename = (split-path $file.FullName -Leaf).split(".")[0]
    $extension = (split-path $file.FullName -Leaf).split(".")[1]

    AutoImportFlatFiles -location $location -file $filename -extension $extension -server "WIN123" -database "DB_DISCOVERY"
}
```

Comment: I'm receiving the "missing ')' in function parameter list"  What gives? Here's how I inserted the your suggested loop function:

    Function AutoImportFlatFiles
(
$Folder= $(read-host "Folder Location ('C:\Test\' okay)")
foreach ($file in (get-childitem $Folder)) {
    $location = split-path $file.FullName -Parent
    $filename = (split-path $file.FullName -Leaf).split(".")[0]
    $extension = (split-path $file.FullName -Leaf).split(".")[1]
$server, 
$database

AutoImportFlatFiles -location $location -file $filename -extension $extension -server "WIN123" -database "DB_DISCOVERY"
}

Comment: @Piros The implementation in my answer was ment to go outside the function. Just leave your function as is and add the code to the end of the script instead of the line `AutoImportFlatFiles -server "WIN123" -database "DB_DISCOVERY"`

Comment: So that's what you meant, sorry I got a bit confused. The code worked like a charm with just a minor tweak to my script. Thanks a bunch!